# Add TMS layer to GeoExt?

Tags: geoext, tile-map-service

Could you please answer to these questions: 
How to add TMS layer to Geoext?
Is it possible?

I couldn't find any information about it....

Comment: which version of geoext that you are talking about?

Comment: Hi, I am talking about http://www.geoext.org/.  Ideally I need to add it in http://opengeo.org/technology/geoext/ example (http://suite.opengeo.org/geoexplorer/composer/).

Comment: Current version of geoext 1.1. I want to use remote url http://212.26.144.110/tile2/map_100000/{zoom}/{x}/{-y}.jpg to get all images. Could you please help me with that?

Comment: I also wonder how to connect TMS to GeoExt FYI it's a direct link to the image `http://212.26.144.110/tile2/orto_10000/11/1218/1343.jpg`